# Support Vector Machine Errors

Tags: data, svm, data-science-model

What is the difference between SVM classification error, SVM margin error, and SVM total error ? Is there any clear definition for them ? And what is C parameter in SVM ? Its totally confusing me !!!

Comment: Can you add some context to where you heard or read these terms?

Comment: I suggest either learning what support vector machines are, through a systematic text, or leaving them alone.

Answer (score 4):

A SVM has 3 very important components: the support vectors, the separating hyperplane and the margin.

[image: components of a SVM]

- When a missclassification occurs, it is because a given point is on the
  wrong side of the separating hyperplane, and that's called a
  **classification error**.
- Whenever a point is inside the margin, that counts as a **margin error**.
- The **total error** of a SVM, is the sum of the classification error and 
  the margin error.

Now, to understand the C parameter, you've got to know that there are 2 types of SVMs:

- Hard margin: these try to maximize the margin without introducing any
  kind of errors.
- Soft margin: which also share the same objective, but they allow for some classification and margin errors to occur. The number of errors allowed is controlled by the C parameter (which is often called the penalty parameter): if C is small, the SVM allows for some errors and therefore reaches better generalization; but as C increases, the SVM penalizes these errors more and more, eventually reaching the point that it allows no errors at all.

As you can see bellow on the left, a very large C restricts the model by not allowing any errors, showing very bad results when outliers are present. On the right, by using a small penalty parameter, we let that negative outlier to be in the positive area, therefore maximizing the margin value and reaching a more respectful separating hyperplane.

[image: comparison of C values]

Although, observe that if you have a soft margin SVM with a very large C value, it will behave just like a hard margin SVM.